# How to get the current url and paste it in mail(as table format) when using for loop in selenium

Tags: java, swing, email, jframe

Hi i am trying to get the current URl of the page which need to be formed as table format in mail and the mail need to be sent to the recipients.

I have written the code,i need to get the URL generated in for loop and paste it in mail as table format

I need to realign the code?.Because now the mail  is getting triggered before the actions and also i am getting the values generated in for loop.

Is there anyother way to execute this?

```
public class Mail extends JFrame {

    public static String start = "<html>\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "<style>\n" +
           "table, th, td {\n" +
            "  border: 1px solid black;\n" +
            "  border-collapse: collapse;\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "</style>\n" +
            "</head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "Hi,<br>";
    public static String htmlMsg ="";

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Mail frame = new Mail();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Mail() {
        htmlMsg = htmlMsg.concat("<br><br>Mobile TestRail Links <br>"+
                "  <table style=\"width:100%\">\n" +
                "  <tr bgcolor=\"#F83911\">\n" +
                "    <th>Locale</th>\n" +
                "    <th>TestRail Link</th>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 512, 263);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("zzz:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 104, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("abc");
        comboBox.addItem("cde");

        comboBox.setBounds(124, 11, 331, 20);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);          

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("1");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 53, 79, 34);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1); 

        List<JCheckBox> locales = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("ram");
        chckbxNewCheckBox.setBounds(17, 94, 63, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("john");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_1.setBounds(104, 94, 63, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2 = new JCheckBox("man");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_2.setBounds(177, 94, 72, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3 = new JCheckBox("boy");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_3.setBounds(17, 133, 63, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4 = new JCheckBox("qwe");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_4.setBounds(104, 133, 63, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5 = new JCheckBox("asd");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_5.setBounds(177, 133, 72, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_6 = new JCheckBox("987");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_6.setBounds(17, 174, 63, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_7 = new JCheckBox("321");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_7.setBounds(104, 174, 63, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7);

        JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_8 = new JCheckBox("qwe");
        chckbxNewCheckBox_8.setBounds(177, 174, 72, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_8);
        locales.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_8);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("qweert");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("abc"))
                {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","call from path");
                    WebDriver aru=new ChromeDriver();
                    aru.manage().window().maximize();
                    aru.get("https://example.com");

                    //Login
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("zzz");
                    aru.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("yyy");
                    aru.findElement(By.id("button_primary")).click(); //Login
                    //aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"button_primary\"]/span")).click();
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("loginpage-button-sso-disable loginpage-button-sso-disable-hover  loginpage-button-sso-disable-active")).click();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    for(JCheckBox checkbox : locales)
                    {
                        if(checkbox.isSelected())
                        {
                            aru.get("xyz.com");
                            aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"suite-22496\"]/div[2]/div[1]/a")).click();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content-header\"]/div/div[2]/a[1]")).click();
                            aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"includeSpecific\"]")).click();
                            aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"includeSpecificInfo\"]/a")).click();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"selectCasesNode-744350\"]/input")).click();
                            aru.findElement(By.id("selectCasesSubmit")).click();


                            aru.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
                            DateFormat today = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy ");
                            Date palani = new Date();
                            String content= today.format(palani);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("aaa" + checkbox.getText() + " - "+content);


                            //Mail text locales
                            htmlMsg = htmlMsg.concat(
                                    "    <tr>\n" +
                                            "    <td align=\"center\">" + checkbox.getText() + "</td>\n" +
                                            "    <td align=\"center\">" + aru.getCurrentUrl()+ "</td>\n" +
                                            "    </tr>\n");
                            htmlMsg = htmlMsg.concat("</table><br><br>\n");
                        }

                        else
                        {

                        }       
                    }
                }                       
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select from list");
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(285, 122, 169, 34);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }

    public static void se(String msg) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.example.com");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("syz@gmail.com"));
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("abc@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Vurrent URlLinks");
            msg = start + msg +
                    "<br>Note: This is an automated email , please don't reply to this email. " 
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>";
            System.out.println(msg);
            message.setContent(msg, "text/html");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("=====Email Sent=====");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {}}

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders ..

Comment: .. for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).